# Web socket request gets garbage collected while in use

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following ASP.NET Core MVC controller action. It is stripped of most real code.

```cs
[Route("ws")]
public async Task WebSocket()
{
    using (var data = new Data()) 
    {
        if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest) 
        {
            using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
            // Here goes the websocket usage, removed for clean repro
            await tcs.Task;
        }
        else 
        {
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
        }
    }
}

class Data : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    ~Data()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data disposed");
    }
}
```

The problem is that all of this (data and any other resources used at the comment) gets garbage collected. The web socket is still connected. This code is very close to the MS ASP.NET Core docs example for web sockets in MVC controller (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-7.0#accept-websocket-requests).

Why is the request Task (I guess) GCed by ASP.NET Core while the TCS is not completed and the action Task also is not completed?

Comment: I should clarify that I get the "Data disposed" message at GC and never hit the Data.Dispose() call.